# XAMPP for Mac rewriting issue when using virtual hosts

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp

I'm not sure what's going on here, I'm far more used to a Windows XAMPP environment, so this is all a bit new to me. Long story short, I'm having some trouble getting a virtual host on XAMPP to correctly show the document root's contents.

I set the `httpd.conf` in the XAMPP folder to include the `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file, and I set my virtual host as follows:

```
 <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> 
ServerName spacexstats 
DocumentRoot "/Volumes/PATRIOT 32/spacexstats” 
<Directory "/Volumes/PATRIOT 32/spacexstats”> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI AddType text/shtml .shtml 
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml 
AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
</Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

From here, I added this to my hosts list in `etc/hosts` by setting:

```
127.0.0.1 spacexstats
```

Upon restarting XAMPP, I attempt to navigate to `spacexstats` in my browser (have cleared the cache), but instead of being delivered my expected `index.php` file, I'm redirected to `spacexstats/xampp` which is essentially the XAMPP splash screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at your quotes `”` which is invalid is this typo?

Comment: @RahilWazir yep, I should be using the standard quotes, but changing it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: See your apache error logs for more info.

Comment: But it's not an error in the eyes of Apache. It's just not doing what I'm expecting it to do.